# "stand one one's hands against the wall" or "lean aginst the wall standing on one's hands"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Tell me please the following sentences are correct and natural.

> To do a proper handstand, first you have to be able to stand on your hand against the wall.
>
> To do a proper handstand, first you have to be able to lean against the wall standing on your hands.

Comment: Neither sentence is natural or even necessarily meaningful. You don't stand on your hands against the wall.

Comment: @JasonBassford — I think that idea works okay, given that the action is a "hand stand". It's pretty clear that you're leaning against a wall while standing on your hands.

Comment: You need the "lean" to differentiate between what you hands and your body are doing. In the first example, only your hands are specified (without reading in a lot of context)..

Comment: What do I say when I want someone not to lean against the wall when they are doing a handstand near a wall? Is "don't lean against the wall" ok?

Comment: Maybe "stay clear of the wall", "don't touch the wall", but "don't lean against the wall" is okay too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second is better than the first. I might modify 1. like so:

1. Before being ready to do a proper handstand, you first have to be able to stand on your hands while leaning against the wall.

I would tweak 2. just a little:

To do a proper handstand, you first have to be able to lean against a wall while standing on your hands.

Answer (score 2):

I will not attempt to answer your specific question, instead suggest a technique for constructing quality sentences.

I presume the sentence you are asking about comes with a context and a lot of words in your draft have already been used in the preceding sentences.

As your first cut for the next idea you want to explain, try writing down **just** words you will need for this idea - but which you have **not yet used**. In this case, you might get something like this:

> proper handstand learn against a wall.

Now try filling out those words until you get a grammatically complete sentence. You might then get to this:

> To do a proper handstand, learn how to do it leaning against a wall.

In my opinion, that sounds much better than either of your examples because it focuses on the new concept you are attempting to explain.